# Redirect all pages to a specific page of a new domain but exclude specific pages

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all pages of `example.com` to a specific page `domain.com/rebrand-explained`

except for the following pages, they need to be going to the same slug on the new domain for example:

`example.com/secure-payment` to `domain.com/secure-payment`

`example.com/blog/news/please-help` to `domain.com/blog/news/please-help`

Answer (score 1):

Got it working using the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^secure-payment$ https://domain.com/secure-payment [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^blog/news/please-help$ https://domain.com/blog/news/please-help [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com/rebrand-explained/ [L,NC,R=301]
```